# Cloudflare chokes on base64 posted string coming from toDataURL()

Tags: cloudflare, mediatemple

In 99% of the cases, Cloudflare chokes on a base64 posted string coming from Javascript's `toDataURL()` resulting in a "502 Bad Gateway" error. In some rare occasions the post succeeds, but for most of the time the error appears.

How can I work around that?

Below the actual POST variables. Note that the base64 string has been shortened for demonstration reasons (otherwise it would be a very very long blob).

```
action=createCanvasImg&q=loremipsum.png&hash=cd09a136415d11542410f62eb89c6221&string=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAA
```

Update 1: The host is Mediatemple

Update 2: I posted a [more general "Bad Gateway" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741777/cloudflare-bad-gateway-502-error) on Stackoverflow, so this problem may not be related to the specific case described above.

Answer (score 1):

"disabled it" isn't an answer. If you didn't already contact CloudFlare's support team with full details please do that so we can actually investigate the issue.