# Cloudflare Bad Gateway 502 error

Tags: cloudflare

Myself and my users are often running into a `Cloudflare Bad Gateway 502 error`. Trying to figure out what goes wrong is hard, because Cloudflare blames the hosting company and the hosting company blames Cloudflare. A typical situation when using Cloudflare.

What I noticed is that nothing actually fails. The host receives the request and is handling the request just fine but which sometimes takes a bit longer than usual to complete. But Cloudflare can't wait and instead throws a `Bad Gateway` error, while the script is actually still running.

I've noticed this behavior when performing heavy back-end tasks (like generating +50 PDFs). My users notice this when they try to upload an image (which often starts a re-sizing task).

Is there a way I can configure my server so that Cloudflare knows that the request is still being processed? Or should I just ditch Cloudflare overall?

Comment: What about marking your own answer as correct?

Answer (score 9):

The culprit was Railgun. After disabling Railgun (in Cloudflare's control panel) the `Bad Gateway 502` errors immediately disappeared.

Comment: This is pretty common if Railgun isn't properly configured. I've tried modifying Railgun settings in a live environment (I know, I shouldn't) and every time I update them and restart Railgun, people get 521 errors for a while.

Comment: Cloudflare always cuts the connection 5 minutes after waiting, actually I didn't found any solution, more than optimize the server and to answer everything under 5 minutes. I don't have Railgun. Try yourself a request taking more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through this error for quite a long time, Cloudflare support wasn't able to guide me.
To solve this I tried multiple tweaks and tricks.
the successful one was changing your https to HTTP in your database > wp_option.
for example :

1. https://xxxxx.com/ to http://xxxxx.com/
2. switching your SSL setting to "full" in Cloudflare settings.
   this should work fine, good luck.

Comment: No need to post real addresses to prove your point. This could be seen as spam and give you a ban

Answer (score 0):

I have researched on this error very deeply and what I found the result https://modernbreeze.in/error-502-bad-gateway-cloudflare-how-to-fix-in-wordpress/
I noted down in the above blog post. Please read and let me know if it's solved or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to mention the main points in your answer itself. If it does not completely answer the question, you can comment it below the asked question.